# Is there a right way to export/import types in react/nextjs applications

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, types, react-typescript

i want to use a type of an API response, and i wonder if there's a way to export and import those types

```
// pages/users.tsx

type Post = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  address: {
    street: string;
    suite: string;
    city: string;
    zipcode: string;
    geo: {
      lat: string;
      lng: string;
    };
  };
  phone: string;
  website: string;
  company: {
    name: string;
    catchPhrase: string;
    bs: string;
  };
};


export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<{
  posts: Post[];
}> = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const posts: Post[] = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
};

const users: React.FC<
  InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps> & Props
> = ({ posts, isLogged }): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
      <User posts={posts} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default users;
```

and i want to re-use the type of `Post`

```
// pages/user.tsx

import { FC } from "react";

type Props = {
  posts: Post[]; // cannot find name 'Post'
};

const User: FC<Props> = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map(
        ({
          name,
          id,

          company: { name: CompanyName, catchPhrase },
          address: { city, zipcode },
        }) => {
          console.log(CompanyName);
          return <h1 key={id}>City: {city}</h1>;
        }
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default User;
```

so how to export and import types in the right way, should i create the `type` folder with all types in the global project structure? or just create a `types.ts` on each folder, and re-use it.

Comment: Export your `Post` type and import it where you need it. It's up to you how you want to organize your types, but it's erroring because you aren't importing/exporting the type.

Answer (score 0):

```
// pages/users.tsx
export type Post = {...};

// pages/user.tsx
import { Post } from './users';
```

Answer (score 0):

Better create a new folder at src "interfaces/shared", there create a separate file for the type.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).